# cannot connect to postgres

Tags: node.js, linux, postgresql, sequelize.js

A couple of days ago i migrated from windows to linux and i have been doing pretty great until i had to go back to working on a particular project with my colleagues and now i cannot seem to get the application to even start because of the database configuration which keeps getting rejected and throwing an error.

### my .env file

```
## Setup NODE_ENV
NODE_ENV=development

## Setup your psql development database
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS= password
DB_NAME=data
DB_HOST=localhost
```

now this .env configuration works fine on my windows machine but when i try to work with it on linux i get the following error

```
ERROR: password authentication failed for user "optimusPrime"
```

Can someone explain why it is seeing optimusPrime(which is my working name) `optimusPrime@root` as the user instead of postgres and how can i configure it or edit the code such that it works with my Node.js application on linux(i and my team are using the sequelize ORM) the way it did on windows. The configuration file looks like

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: 'postgres',
  }
 }
```

This is the error from the log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/home/optimusPrime/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/optimusPrime/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'postinstall'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.1
3 info using node@v12.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'postinstall' ]
5 info lifecycle Dae-Alright-Backend@1.0.0~postinstall: Dae-Alright-Backend@1.0.0
6 verbose lifecycle Dae-Alright-Backend@1.0.0~postinstall: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle Dae-Alright-Backend@1.0.0~postinstall: PATH: /home/optimusPrime/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/optimusPrime/Documents/projects/Dae-Alright-Backend/node_modules/.bin:/home/optimusPrime/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/bin:/home/optimusPrime/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
8 verbose lifecycle Dae-Alright-Backend@1.0.0~postinstall: CWD: /home/optimusPrime/Documents/projects/Dae-Alright-Backend
9 silly lifecycle Dae-Alright-Backend@1.0.0~postinstall: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run build && npm run db:migrate' ]
10 silly lifecycle Dae-Alright-Backend@1.0.0~postinstall: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
11 info lifecycle Dae-Alright-Backend@1.0.0~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
12 verbose stack Error: Dae-Alright-Backend@1.0.0 postinstall: `npm run build && npm run db:migrate`
12 verbose stack Exit status 1
12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/optimusPrime/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/lib/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/optimusPrime/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/lib/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1023:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:281:5)
13 verbose pkgid Dae-Alright-Backend@1.0.0
14 verbose cwd /home/optimusPrime/Documents/projects/Dae-Alright-Backend
15 verbose Linux 4.15.0-54-generic
16 verbose argv "/home/optimusPrime/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/bin/node" "/home/optimusPrime/.nvm/versions/node/v12.0.0/bin/npm" "run" "postinstall"
17 verbose node v12.0.0
18 verbose npm  v6.13.1
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error errno 1
21 error Dae-Alright-Backend@1.0.0 postinstall: `npm run build && npm run db:migrate`
21 error Exit status 1
22 error Failed at the Dae-Alright-Backend@1.0.0 postinstall script.
22 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
23 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Look in the server log file for a more complete error message. The error message sent to the unauthenticated user is intentionally vague.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the output in the log file

Comment: That is the app server log file.  You need the PostgreSQL server log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently my `pg_hba.conf` file needed to be edited better

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf
```

so i opened it as super user and edited it such that the user I wanted to use(which i created initially when i started the project) and changed it from md5 to trust

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                trust

local   all             otherUser                               trust
```

Also for security it turns out that if i made the otherUser a postgres super user i can change it's password and I will also be able to make use of it in the project